# Mule duplicates files when writing to JMS Queue

Tags: jms, mule, activemq-classic, mule-cluster

I have a Mule HA cluster with 3 instances running. Each instance have a file connector that picks files from a shared location, and the picked files are written into an Active MQ queue. The process is simple enough but the File connector keeps writing duplicate files in to the Active MQ queue. How do I resolve this issue to keep the file count constant?

Comment: Can you check if it's the same Mule instance that polls the same file multiple times, or if the polling occurs in several instances in the pool?

Comment: duplicate from here? http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/34165/duplicate-file-poling-from-the-shared-directory-in.html did you try these solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try appending timestamp to the filename and with some delimiter add your counter. Hope this helps.